# Creation of apk for android application in visual studio 2015 using xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Presently am developing an android application using xamarin, visual studio 2015. Before I used to get export android package option I usually get in  Build in release mode, but presently am not getting it? How can we create apk in this.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click your android project there should be an "Archive..." option.

From there click distribute and follow the prompts.

a quick search brought me here: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-archiving-and-publishing-made-easy/

Comment: For people who have the same error I had when trying to archive(*Shared Mono runtime is enabled for 'MyApp.Android'*.): https://stackoverflow.com/q/48982732/4815184