# How do you disable "Use Mono Shared Runtime" in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, apk

I'm following this guide
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-and-distributing-android-app-using-visual-studio-2017/ to generate the APK file for my app, however when I'm archiving the project it gives me the following error:

**Mono Shared runtime is enabled for 'MyApp.Android'.**

**The selected build configuration is using the Mono shared runtime for faster deployment. Apps cannot be archived with this setting enabled.**

**Please ensure that you are using a release configuration and that the "Use Mono Shared Runtime" option is your project's build options is unchecked.**

How do I disable that option in Visual Studio 2017?

Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On your project, right click, select `Properties`, and you will see this:

[image]

**UPDATE**: Like @Chandan Y S had said, we need to restart VS as well

Comment: With the above solution, we need to restart Visual Studio as well.

Comment: @ChandanYS Yes. Restart is Required

Comment: Man, I struck up with this for almost a week, just restarting VS worked... thank you

Comment: @ChandanYS Thanks, restarting VS was the key information here for me... Took me an hour to fiddle with various settings, before noticing this, and solving all my problems! ^^

Comment: @RalfStauder Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Swith to Release and then begin Archive... (work in VS 2019)

Answer (score 4):

Right click on Android solution > Select Android Options > Uncheck the option *Enable developer instrumentation(debugging & profiling)*

In Visual Studio Enterprise edition